# Updating Select2 selected elements when Angular model changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select2

I'm working on a project for deploying software through an AngularJS UI. On the current view, you have to select what environment a deployment is for. The possible list of environments is stored in the scope and is what the options for the select are built from:

```
<select ui-select2="{ }" data-placeholder="All Environments" ng-model="transformParams.EnvironmentIds" multiple="multiple" class="input-xxlarge">
  <option ng-repeat="environment in environments" value="{{ environment.Id }}">{{ environment.Name }}</option>
</select>
```

Also on this page, there is a drop down that changes the current item that the environment is going to be set for. Choosing an existing item from the dropdown should take the `Environments` property from the existing item and select the correct elements in my Select2 box. This would then obviously update the `transformParams.EnvironmentIds` model. I've tried updating that model to change which environments are select but to no avail.

I've seen the bugfix [to Angular 1.2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2/issues/110) but I am stuck on 1.0.7 and don't have the option to upgrade Angular at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using some options for the select2:

```
<select ui-select2="selectOptions" data-placeholder="All Environments" ng-model="transformParams.EnvironmentIds" multiple="multiple" class="input-xxlarge">
    <option ng-repeat="env in environments" value="{{ env.Id }}">{{ env.Name }}</option>
</select>
```

With the options being defined in the controller:

```
$scope.selectOptions = {
    'multiple': true,
    'simple_tags': true,
    'initSelection': function (element, callback) {
        callback($(element).data('$ngModelController').$modelValue);
    }
}
```